# Open a modal when username is clicked within a flat list react native

Tags: react-native

I want to open a modal that displays a users profile when the username within a flat list element is clicked. For example, here is the flatlist element:

[image]

When a user clicks the username "tempUN", the modal should open with user "tempUN" profile information.

Currently, I am rendering the cell with all the information like above, and using a touchable opacity that should open the modal:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => openModal(username)}> 
         <Text style = {styles.tradeText}> {username} </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This is what openModal looks like:

```
export function openModal(username){
if (username) {
    console.log(username)
    return(
        <View>
            <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            visible={true}
            onRequestClose={() => {
                Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
            }}
            >
            <View>
                <View>
                <Text style={styles.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>

                </View>
            </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    )
}
}
```

When I click the username, the console logs the username, but the modal does not show up. How can I fix this issue, so when I click the username, the modal slides up?

Thanks

Comment: you don't just return the modal view to open the modal, you need to toggle the visible flag. With that said, that modal needs to be part of the view with the initial visible flag set to false. here's an example: https://snack.expo.io/@yoobit0616/modal?&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=8keg0jwttx&supportedPlatforms=android,ios&name=Modal&description=Example%20usage&theme=light&waitForData=true

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!